# String compression in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, compression

Is there a way I can compress a long string (e.g. a long JSON string) in PHP and then decompress it in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037349/how-to-compress-json-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to use gzip compression of the whole output of your PHP script -- and to let the browser handle the decompression, on the client-side.

If you are working with Apache, you can use [**`mod_deflate`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Else, in PHP, you can use [**`ob_gzhandler`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) -- see the example on that manual page.

Then, on the client-side *(browser)*, you have nothing to do : the decompression will be dealt with automatically.

As a sidenote : using `mod_deflate`, you can configure so CSS, Javascript, HTML *(well, all data that are text)* are compressed the same way -- which will reduce the size of your pages, and speed up their loading a bit ; so, it's worth investigating a bit ;-)

Answer (score -4):

```
  <?php
     $str1 = "Test";
     $str2 = "Test";
     if ($str1 == "Test") echo "OK-1";
     if ($str1 == $str2) echo "OK-2";
  ?>
```

Comment: Your "answers" have several shortcomings; they are not self-explanatory, they don't address OP's question, and there are more than one.

Comment: compress, not compare. And spamming the question with multiple useless answers is frowned upon

Answer (score -4):

```
function isSameString( s1, s2 )
  {
    alert( "s1: " + s1.toString() );
    alert( "s2: " + s2.toString() );

    return s1.toString() == s2.toString();
  }
```

Comment: How do either of your answers address *compression*?

Comment: And why would anyone do this when `return s1.toString() == s2.toString()` is more readable *and* does the exact same?

Comment: if ( s1.toString() == s2.toString() )
this i do because i use function...........     if we want to apply that same for more time so............... otherwise at all place we have to write

Comment: What? What I was saying is that `return s1.toString() == s2.toString()` is *identical* to `if (s1.toString() == s2.toString()) { return true; } else { return false; }`.